# how to properly check for an existing object in parse with swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, object, parse-platform

I've made a function that creates a "favorite" object back in parse with the tap of a favorite button on the UI :

```
//MARK: Create the favorite object
    func createFavorite(){
        let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
        let currentBook = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Books", objectId: objectIdSelected)
        let favorite = PFObject(className:"Favorites")
        favorite["user"] = currentUser
        favorite["books"] = currentBook
        favorite.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                // success
            } else {
                // There was a problem, check error.description
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I am attempting to create a query that checks to see if a favorite object with those exact properties exists using the following logic, I've placed it in the viewDidLoad of a VC that shows a specific book:

```
//MARK: Check if there is a favorite object available
    func isFavoritedByUser(){
        let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
        let currentBook = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Books", objectId: objectIdSelected)
        let query = PFQuery(className:"Favorites")
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: currentUser!)
        query.whereKey("books", equalTo: currentBook)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if objects != nil {

                print("this book was favorited by this user")

            } else if objects == nil {

                print("this book WAS NOT favorited by this user")

            } else if error == nil {

                // succeed

            } else if error != nil {

                // There was a problem, check error.description
            }
        }
    }
```

However, even if no favorite object with those properties exists back in my parse class, it still prints "this book was favorited by this user".. what am i missing here?

Comment: You better check error first and put `if object != nil` in `else if error == nil`.

Comment: When you are trying to obtain data from the user class you should use a _User query,  `PFUser.query` . Then you query the user class for data in a column for a particular user. Is "favorites" a column in your user class?

Comment: no you see, Favorites is a Class & "user" is a pointer column to `_User` @MikeG

Comment: i did that prior but i thought it was just checking to see if no error occurred and not the inner else statement that was causing the issue @trick14

Answer (score 0):

The list existing is not proof. That simply proves that some kinda of error weren't observed.

You should check that there was no error first, then you should check that the list of objects has one item in it.

If the list has more than one item then you're creating duplicates and you should fix that...

Answer (score 0):

What you're getting returned is an array, as long as there isn't an error. So, rather than checking for nil, you should be checking the content of the returned array (*objects*) to see if there is anything in there.

In Parse's guide, you can see what they recommend for this function call:
https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries

Additionally, Parse recommends considering getFirstObjectInBackground instead if this query only ever needs to return a single object, so that might be something to consider as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was i was checking to see if `object` was nil rather then checking for the count, here is the correct code:

```
//MARK: Check if there is a favorite object available
    func isFavoritedByUser(){
        let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
        let currentBook = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Books", objectId: objectIdSelected)
        let query = PFQuery(className:"Favorites")
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: currentUser!)
        query.whereKey("books", equalTo: currentBook)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                if object?.count > 0{

                print("this book was favorited by this user")

                } else {

                    print("this book WAS NOT favorited by this user")
                }

            } else {

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you can just check the dictionary on an object like so:

```
rideParse["driver"] == nil
```

If it exists, then you will get the pointer. If it doesn't/you did not query to include the pointer, then it will just return nil.